# javascript function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, function

I have the following code in an external javascript file.  I am getting an error on this line below:   `guessNum = inGuess.parseInt();`
firebug tells me the parseInt is not a function.  I thought all things in js were basically objects (at least that is what I remember reading in W3School).  I am sure this is something simple, I am just stuck. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

```
function inputNum() 
{
/*  initialize variables   */
var inGuess = "";
var loopCt;
var guessResult = "";
var correctNum = 26;
var guessNum = 0;

for (loopCt=1;loopCt<11;loopCt++)
{
    inGuess = prompt("Please enter your guess(enter -1 to exit) Do not press Enter","0");
    if (inGuess == "-1")  { break; }
    if (inGuess==null || inGuess=="")
    {
        alert("Blanks are not allowed.  To exit enter '-1'.");
    } 
    else
    {
        guessNum = inGuess.parseInt(); 
        if (inGuess == "26")
        {
            alert("Congratulations, you guess correctly!");
            guessResult="Correct!";
        }
        else
        if (guessNum < correctNum)
        {
            guessResult="Too low";
        }
        else
        {
            guessResult="Too high";
        }

        document.getElementById('emp'+loopCt).innerHTML=inGuess;
        document.getElementById('ct'+loopCt).innerHTML=guessResult;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Use [MDN for docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), not W3Schools.

Answer (score 5):

`parseInt` is a global function. You are trying to access it off of a string object, where it doesn't exist.

```
guessNum = parseInt(inGuess, 10); // Tell it what base to use.  Protect against 08 being interpretued as octal.
```

That would be the correct way to handle this.

[parseInt Mozilla Developer Network Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

- Footnote - parseInt can return `NaN` which when compared with `typeof` actually returns `number`

Answer (score 2):

`parseInt` is a method on `window`, not on a string. You want

```
guessNum = parseInt(inGuess, 10);
```

The second argument insures that your code will treat the first argument as a base-10 number, meaning it will correctly parse `"010"` as `10` and reject `"0x10"` instead of parsing it as `16`.

> I thought all things in js were basically objects

They *are* objects, but that doesn't mean that all objects have the same set of methods defined on them.

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to use it like that for whatever exotic reason, you can define prototype on the String object:

```
String.prototype.parseInt = function() {

    return parseInt(this,10);
}

var inGuess = "26";

alert(inGuess.parseInt());
```

Comment: Ah, durr, yeah. Sorry :p

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax isn't quite right... From the console:

```
> x = parseInt("2", 10)
2
```

Also, something to keep in mind, which come from the docs...

> If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal) or 10 (decimal).  Exactly which radix is chosen is implementation-dependent.  ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used, but not all browsers support this yet.  For this reason **always specify a radix when using parseInt**.

**[parseInt() Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)**

Answer (score 0):

inGuess is a string and string does not have parseInt function. parseInt is a global function.

do this:

```
guessNum = parseInt(inGuess);
```